Principle of relativity and Lorentz invariance and their mathematical description
From wikipedia

In physics, the principle of relativity is the requirement that the equations describing the laws of physics have the same form in all admissible frames of reference.

I don't understand we can "check" or "impose" Lorentz invariance of the theory or the Lagrangian.I wonder if I have the Lagrangian of, for example, a free scalar field.
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2$$
How to treat it mathematically? Whether the statement "have the same form in all admissible frames of reference(of course now we consider inertial frames)." implies that the Lagrangian expressed in two different coordinate system(chart) X and Y should be the same.And whether this is equivalent to "$\mathcal L$ is invariant under the action of Lorentz group."?
To be more concrete,let's consider the standard steps in many (most,maybe) QFT books:
For $x^\mu \to x^\mu + \epsilon \Delta x^\mu$，we have：
\begin{equation}
\Delta \phi = \epsilon \Delta x^\mu \partial_\mu \phi
\end{equation}
And the Lagrangian：
\begin{equation}
\delta \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}'(\phi + \Delta \phi, \partial_\mu \phi + \partial_\mu \Delta \phi) - \mathcal{L}(\phi, \partial_\mu \phi) = 0
\end{equation}
With E-L equation and the partial integral,we finally have：
\begin{equation}
0=\delta \mathcal L = \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \Delta \phi
\end{equation}
So for this case, there are 2 questions:
1.what is the meaning of "$0=\delta \mathcal L$" in this case?
$\delta \mathcal L$ always equals to 0? Or we want it to be 0? or other things?
And even the outcome itself is confusing, when we perform a infinitesimal coordiante transformation, we always get an equivalent E.o.M. because the lagrangian only differred by a total derivative term!
2.Whether the substraction between $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L'$ depends on the fact that our base manifold is flat? Because if we consider a scalar field on M, in general seems we can't do substraction in differnt coordiante system.
Sincerely thank you for your answering.


The correct statement is that if a transformation parameterized by $\epsilon$ is a continuous symmetry, then $\delta_\epsilon L=\partial_\mu V^\mu$, where $\delta_\epsilon L$ is the first-order variation of the Lagrangian under the transformation, and $\partial_\mu V^\mu$ is a total derivative. People get so used to throwing out total derivatives that some people might sloppily write "$=0$" to mean "$=0$ up to a total derivative," however in the context of deriving Noether currents you do want to keep track of the total derivative term since it could contribute to the current. Importantly, the equality here is off shell, meaning that you are not supposed to use the equations of motion to derive it. (Otherwise, the condition $\delta_\epsilon L = \partial_\mu V^\mu$ would be trivially satisfied, since the Euler-Lagrange equations are derived by finding special field values where the first order variation vanishes for any variation).

The careful way to do this comparison uses a Lie derivative.


As for generally, "how to treat symmetries mathematically," the main point is that the fields are representations of an underlying symmetry group. So you can write down the list of properties that a representation has to satisfy and check that (say) transformations on a scalar field follow those properties. (As an aside, one possibly confusing thing is that mathematicians use the word "representation" to refer to the matrices that act on vectors in a vector space, because they are more interested in the properties of the transformations, whereas physicists use the word "representation" to refer to vectors in that vector space, because the vectors end up corresponding to fields/particles which are the things we actually care about). The action is invariant under the group of symmetries.

Thank you for your answering. Your answer 1 is the most clear one I have ever seen. And I still wanna check something I dont fully understand. First, what is the meaning of use a Lie derivative?  Seems Lie derivative needs a tensor field and a vector field, now I guess the tensor field is the Lagrangian, but where is the vector field? The killing field?  And I also don't  understand "fields are representations", so indeed are they operator representations of group? Could you plz shortly introduce it?

@MakiseKurisu The vector in the lie derivative is a tangent vector pointing in the direction you want to take the derivative. It's analogous to a unit vector you would dot with the gradient to create a partial derivative. You can take the Lie derivative of a scalar function, that is explained on the page I linked above here. It is like an ordinary derivative but you are careful to define all the mappings so that you are comparing apples and apples, and you avoid the paradoxical situation in your question.

In terms of representations, it's a complicated enough story that my recommendation is that you read a textbook to get a clear understanding of what's going on. A classic one is "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" by Georgi (rumor has it that if you search the title and author you might stumble on a relevant pdf file). The short answer to your question "are they operator representations of the group" is: classically the fields are just normal functions, in QFT they are operators.
